# How to use functions from one class in another?

Tags: c++, class

I have three classes, A, B, and C. Class C includes objects of type A and B. In C's .cpp file, when I try to use A or B methods (in this case, a 'print' method I wrote) on objects of type A and B, I get "Method 'printA' not resolved". I have included A.h, B.h, A.cpp, and B.cpp in C.cpp and have written 'class A' and 'class B' in C.h. How do I let my C.cpp file access the methods for A and B?

Here is what I have so far for the C.cpp file:

```
    #include "C.h"
    #include "A.h"
    #include "A.cpp"
    #include "B.h"
    #include "B.cpp"
    using namespace std;

    void C::printC(){
        a.printA();
        b.printB();
    }
```

Where 'a' and 'b' were defined as objects of type A and B in the C.h file.

Comment: Why are you including a .cpp file?

Comment: You should use `C.h` just for declarations, not for definitions

Comment: You should add `A.cpp`, `B.cpp` and `C.cpp` to the project so that they can be separately compiled and then linked together to form an executable.

Answer (score 3):

In `.h` files you include declarations for your classes whereas `.cpp` files should contain definitions.

You need to include every used declaration directly or via indirection but no definitions (if not inline or templates).

#### X.h

```
#ifndef X_HEADER
#define X_HEADER

struct X
{
  void printX();
};

#endif
```

#### Y.h

```
#ifndef Y_HEADER
#define Y_HEADER

struct Y
{
  void printY();
};

#endif
```

#### Z.h

```
#ifndef Z_HEADER
#define Z_HEADER

#include "X.h"
#include "Y.h"

struct Z
{
  X x;
  Y y;
  void printZ();
};

#endif
```

#### X.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "X.h" // *
void X::printX () { std::cout << "X"; }
```

#### Y.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Y.h" // **
void Y::printY() { std::cout << "Y"; }
```

#### Z.cpp

```
#include "Z.h" // also includes X.h and Y.h due to * and **
// no need to include X.h and Y.h seperately here
// also no need to include any cpp file

void Z::printZ()
{ 
  x.printX(); 
  y.printY(); 
}
```

Then you need to compile `X.cpp`, `Y.cpp` and `Z.cpp` seperately and link the into an executable together with the compilation unit containing your `int main(/**/)` function.